# How to get Difference in time data kept in two different files in Unix?

Tags: perl, unix

I Have Two files each with some 200K Timestamps in a single column. I want to find the difference between each rows(mapped one to one) in seconds.

For example:

One file has `2013-06-04 11:21:28` and Second file `2013-06-04 11:21:55` in the same row, so I want to get the output as 27. That is 27 seconds.

Can some one help me with a Unix command to get this done?

Comment: Something like this: `$ echo $(date -d'2013-06-04 11:21:55' '+%s') - $(date -d'2013-06-04 11:21:28' '+%s') | bc` ==> gives 27.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hroptatyr/dateutils ddif to the rescue

```
ddiff 2012-03-01T12:17:00 2012-03-02T14:00:00
=>
  92580s
```

Comment: he shoud `paste` the files before that and use `xargs`

Answer (score 1):

```
paste -d, a b | while IFS=, read t1 t2
do
    echo "$(( $( date -d "$t2" +%s ) - $( date -d "$t1" +%s ) ))"
done
```

That should do it.

Filenames are assumed to be "a" and "b".